# Bootstrap 4 nav-tabs dropdown menu color when open

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to change the color of the dropdown menu in my navigation tabs when it is open (in this case blue and red), but it goes back to white when I let go of the mouse. How would I make it so when the dropdown menu appears white, it instead stays blue? My code is below if anybody can help.

[What it looks like right now](https://gyazo.com/7b2dd53933942d8c2e903e19687cfed5)

My HTML

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Projects</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-center">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#algorithms-data">Algorithms and Data Structures</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#programming-lab">Programming Lab</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#computer-systems">Computer Systems Organization</a>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

My CSS:

```
.dropdown-menu {
    background-color: var(--dark-gray);
    border-top: 1px solid white;
    border-right: 1px solid white;
    border-left: 1px solid white;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}

.dropdown-item:hover {
    background-color: var(--gray);
}

.dropdown-toggle.active {
    background-color: blue;
}

.dropdown-toggle:active, .open .dropdown-toggle {
    background-color: blue !important;
    color: red !important;
}
```

Comment: please make working fiddle with full code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `:focus`

```
.dropdown-toggle:focus{...}
```

```css
.dropdown-menu {
    background-color: var(--dark-gray);
    border-top: 1px solid white;
    border-right: 1px solid white;
    border-left: 1px solid white;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}

.dropdown-item:hover {
    background-color: var(--gray);
}

.dropdown-toggle.active {
    background-color: blue;
}

.dropdown-toggle:active, .open .dropdown-toggle,.dropdown-toggle:focus {
    background-color: blue !important;
    color: red !important;
}
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Projects</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-center">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#algorithms-data">Algorithms and Data Structures</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#programming-lab">Programming Lab</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#computer-systems">Computer Systems Organization</a>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: tell me for more help!

Comment: Using focus solved the original problem, but now when I click on dropdown-items the dropdown-toggle turns to white. Any ideas on how to fix that? @לבני מלכה

Comment: you have to do it in Jquery onclick item set focus to parent(you can not do it in css because it child to parent)

Comment: I see what you did, but what I meant was when I hold my mouse click on the dropdown items, the dropdown toggle itself turns to white instead of staying as blue.

Comment: Just figured it out using jQuery's .focus(). Thank you for the effort though.